# how to get a list in a json file with complex data in flutter dart

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I have some nested json data here:

```
 [
    {
        "title": "A1",
        "startPage": 2,
        "totalPage": 10,
        "endPage": 11,
        "astartPage": 33,
        "aendPage": 42,
        "subtitle1": [
            {
                "subname1": "A11",
                "s1startPage": 2,
                "s1endPage": 9,
                "subtitle2": [
                    {
                        "subname2": "A111",
                        "s2startPage": 2,
                        "s2endPage": 2,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1111"
                            },
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1112"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subname2": "A112",
                        "s2startPage": 2,
                        "s2endPage": 3,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1121"
                            },
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1122"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "subname1": "A12",
                "s1startPage": 9,
                "s1endPage": 10,
                "subtitle2": [
                    {
                        "subname2": "A121",
                        "s2startPage": 9,
                        "s2endPage": 9,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1211"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subname2": "A122",
                        "s2startPage": 9,
                        "s2endPage": 9,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A1221"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "A2",
        "startPage": 2,
        "totalPage": 10,
        "endPage": 11,
        "astartPage": 33,
        "aendPage": 42,
        "subtitle1": [
            {
                "subname1": "A21",
                "s1startPage": 2,
                "s1endPage": 9,
                "subtitle2": [
                    {
                        "subname2": "A211",
                        "s2startPage": 2,
                        "s2endPage": 2,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2111"
                            },
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2112"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subname2": "A212",
                        "s2startPage": 2,
                        "s2endPage": 3,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2121"
                            },
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2122"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "subname1": "A22",
                "s1startPage": 9,
                "s1endPage": 10,
                "subtitle2": [
                    {
                        "subname2": "A221",
                        "s2startPage": 9,
                        "s2endPage": 9,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2211"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "subname2": "A222",
                        "s2startPage": 9,
                        "s2endPage": 9,
                        "subtitle3": [
                            {
                                "subname3": "A2221"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I use this example since my actual json file is much more longer.. so what i want to get is the value of **"title"** which is **A1** and **A2** in a form of list since i want to use it for my expansion tile in flutter. I have already created the model which is here:

```
class Naglist {
  final List<Title> titles;

  Naglist({
    this.titles,
  });


    factory Naglist.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<Title> title = new List<Title>();
    title = parsedJson.map((i)=>Title.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new Naglist(
      titles: title,
    );
  }

}

class Title {
    

    final String title;
    final int startPage;
    final int totalPage;
    final int endPage;
    final int astartPage;
    final int aendPage;
    final List<Subtitle1> subtitle1;
    
    Title({this.title,this.astartPage,this.totalPage,this.endPage,this.startPage,this.aendPage,this.subtitle1});

    factory Title.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

      var list = parsedJson['subtitle1'] as List;
      //print(list.runtimeType);
      List<Subtitle1> subtitle1list =  list!=null? list.map((i) => Subtitle1.fromJson(i)).toList():new List<Subtitle1>();


    return Title(
      title: parsedJson['title'],
      startPage: parsedJson['startPage'],
      totalPage: parsedJson['totalPage'],
      endPage:parsedJson['endPage'],
      astartPage: parsedJson['astartPage'],
      aendPage: parsedJson['aendPage'],
      subtitle1: subtitle1list
    );
    }
}
class Subtitle1 {
   

    final String subname1;
    final int s1startPage;
    final int s1endPage;
    final List<Subtitle2> subtitle2;
    
    Subtitle1({this.subname1,this.s1startPage,this.s1endPage,this.subtitle2});


    factory Subtitle1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

      var list = parsedJson['subtitle2'] as List;
      //print(list.runtimeType);
      List<Subtitle2> subtitle2list = list!=null? list.map((i) => Subtitle2.fromJson(i)).toList(): new List<Subtitle2>();


    return Subtitle1(
      subname1: parsedJson['subname1'],
      s1startPage: parsedJson['s1startPage'],
      s1endPage:parsedJson['s1endPage'],
      subtitle2: subtitle2list 
    );
    }

}


class Subtitle2 {
    
    final String subname2;
    final int s2startPage;
    final int s2endPage;
    final List<Subtitle3> subtitle3;

    Subtitle2({this.subname2,this.s2startPage,this.s2endPage,this.subtitle3});
    
    factory Subtitle2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

      var list = parsedJson['subtitle3'] as List;
      //print(list.runtimeType);
      List<Subtitle3> subtitle3list = list!=null?list.map((i) => Subtitle3.fromJson(i)).toList():new List<Subtitle3>();


    return Subtitle2(
      subname2: parsedJson['subname2'],
      s2startPage: parsedJson['s2startPage'],
      s2endPage:parsedJson['s2endPage'],
      subtitle3: subtitle3list 
    );
    }
}

class Subtitle3 {

  final String subname3;
  
  Subtitle3({this.subname3});


  factory Subtitle3.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

 return Subtitle3(
   subname3:parsedJson['subname3']
 );
} 

}
```

so I don't really know how to convert to list except getting specific data from this file.. please help i'm new with parsing json data..

i get the specific data using this code:

```
Future<String> _loadNagAdultFromAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Adult.json');
}

Future  nagAdult() async {
  dynamic jsonString = await _loadNagAdultFromAsset();
  var jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  Naglist naglist = Naglist.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  print(naglist.titles);
  print(naglist.titles[0].title);
}
```

which print **[instance of 'Title',instance of 'Title']** and **A1**

Comment: I don't get the problem. You have correctly defined a list with `final List<Title> titles;`

Comment: @w461 i updated the question and i can get only the list which print instance of title and specific data... how can i print `[A1,A2]` the output like this which is a list of data, not the instance.

Comment: If you are not using Built Value package, please check it out https://pub.dev/packages/built_value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite ways to achieve this. Simplest way it to override `toString` method for title class.

```
  @override
  String toString() => title;
```

Now if you will do, `naglist.titles`, it will print [A, B]

Comment: ty this is the simplest solution i did.. i guess i need to work out more with parsing json

Comment: done.. i have 1 more question if possible.. how can i get for every `subname1` in the `subtitle1` since it is not a `List<dynamic>` and its a  `Map<String,dynamic>`.. is there a way to get a list of `subname1` which will print `[A11,A12]`  ?

Comment: here, you need to iterate the list of title objects and form whatever data you want to form.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume `final myList = Naglist(....);`

Then use

`final myTitleList = myList.titles.map((t) => t.title).toList();`

Comment: this work and i dont know why i cannot think of this solution... ty btw

Comment: so the list worked ty. Then, how can i get for every `subname1` in the `subtitle1` since it is not a list and its a  `Map<String,dynamic>`.. is there a way to get a list of `subname1` which will print `[A11,A12]`  ?

Comment: Not sure, I guess something like ˋfinal myTitleList = myList.titles.map((t) => t.subtitle1.map((t1) => t.surname).toList()).toList();  ˋ You might have to tweak this to get it working

Comment: yeah just like that i got it ty

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following class structure.

```
class Naglist {
  String title;
  int startPage;
  int totalPage;
  int endPage;
  int astartPage;
  int aendPage;
  List<Subtitle1> subtitle1;

  Naglist(
      {this.title,
      this.startPage,
      this.totalPage,
      this.endPage,
      this.astartPage,
      this.aendPage,
      this.subtitle1});

  Naglist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    startPage = json['startPage'];
    totalPage = json['totalPage'];
    endPage = json['endPage'];
    astartPage = json['astartPage'];
    aendPage = json['aendPage'];
    if (json['subtitle1'] != null) {
      subtitle1 = new List<Subtitle1>();
      json['subtitle1'].forEach((v) {
        subtitle1.add(new Subtitle1.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['startPage'] = this.startPage;
    data['totalPage'] = this.totalPage;
    data['endPage'] = this.endPage;
    data['astartPage'] = this.astartPage;
    data['aendPage'] = this.aendPage;
    if (this.subtitle1 != null) {
      data['subtitle1'] = this.subtitle1.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Subtitle1 {
  String subname1;
  int s1startPage;
  int s1endPage;
  List<Subtitle2> subtitle2;

  Subtitle1({this.subname1, this.s1startPage, this.s1endPage, this.subtitle2});

  Subtitle1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    subname1 = json['subname1'];
    s1startPage = json['s1startPage'];
    s1endPage = json['s1endPage'];
    if (json['subtitle2'] != null) {
      subtitle2 = new List<Subtitle2>();
      json['subtitle2'].forEach((v) {
        subtitle2.add(new Subtitle2.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['subname1'] = this.subname1;
    data['s1startPage'] = this.s1startPage;
    data['s1endPage'] = this.s1endPage;
    if (this.subtitle2 != null) {
      data['subtitle2'] = this.subtitle2.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Subtitle2 {
  String subname2;
  int s2startPage;
  int s2endPage;
  List<Subtitle3> subtitle3;

  Subtitle2({this.subname2, this.s2startPage, this.s2endPage, this.subtitle3});

  Subtitle2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    subname2 = json['subname2'];
    s2startPage = json['s2startPage'];
    s2endPage = json['s2endPage'];
    if (json['subtitle3'] != null) {
      subtitle3 = new List<Subtitle3>();
      json['subtitle3'].forEach((v) {
        subtitle3.add(new Subtitle3.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['subname2'] = this.subname2;
    data['s2startPage'] = this.s2startPage;
    data['s2endPage'] = this.s2endPage;
    if (this.subtitle3 != null) {
      data['subtitle3'] = this.subtitle3.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Subtitle3 {
  String subname3;

  Subtitle3({this.subname3});

  Subtitle3.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    subname3 = json['subname3'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['subname3'] = this.subname3;
    return data;
  }
}
```